# Django How to call a function in views.py from ajax by clicking submit button with variable

Tags: python-3.x, django, ajax, django-models, django-templates

I am facing issue with calling a functions in views.py from script html
HTML:

```
<form method="POST" class="msger-inputarea">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="text" name="msg" class="msger-input" placeholder="Enter your message...">
    <button type="submit" name="answer" class="msger-send-btn">Send</button>
  </form>

<script type="text/javascript">
 msgerForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
      event.preventDefault();

      const msgText = msgerInput.value;

      if (!msgText) return;

      appendMessage(PERSON_NAME, PERSON_IMG, "right", msgText);
      msgerInput.value = "";
      botResponse(msgText);
    });

    function botResponse(rawText) {
        alert(rawText)
        alert('inside ajax')
        $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'ajaxview' %}",
        method: 'POST',
        data: {'rawText': rawText , csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}'},
        success: function (response) {
            appendMessage(PERSON_NAME, PERSON_IMG, "left", response);
        },
      });
   }
```

URL.py :

```
 path('/ajax-test-view', views.myajaxtestview, name='ajaxview')
```

VIEWS.py :

```
def myajaxtestview(request):
    input = request.POST.get('rawText')
    return HttpResponse(input)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use [**`JsonResponse`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)([Django Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)) in your view `myajaxtestview`.

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def myajaxtestview(request):
    input = request.POST.get('msg')
    return JsonResponse({"message": "My Ajax Test", input: input})
```

AJAX:

```
msgerForm.addEventListener("submit", event => {
    ...
    botResponse($(this).serialize());
});

function botResponse(data) {
    $.ajax({
        url: "{% url 'ajaxview' %}",
        method: 'POST',
        data: data,
        success: function (response) {
            appendMessage(PERSON_NAME, PERSON_IMG, "left", response.message);
        },
    });
}
```

Urls.py:

```
path('ajax-test-view/', views.myajaxtestview, name='ajaxview')
```

Add jQuery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I tried to print(input) but its not printing. The script and url is correct? @NKSM

Comment: @Mohanbaabu, i edited my answer > `botResponse($(this).serialize());`

Comment: input = request.POST.get('rawText') , here i need to change 'rawText' to 'data' @NKSM

Comment: const msgText = msgerInput.value;  botResponse(msgText); I need to pass argument to next function @NKSM Thanks in advances

Comment: @Mohanbaabu, in your view `input = request.POST.get('msg')`

Comment: @Mohanbaabu, and then in $.ajax.success use `response.message` > `appendMessage(PERSON_NAME, PERSON_IMG, "left", response.message)`

Comment: @Mohanbaabu, what did you `alert($(this).serialize());`

Comment: @Mohanbaabu, i you print in your view print(request.body). See you anything?

Comment: request to join a call, its a small discussion

Comment: @Mohanbaabu, i am not be able to do a call. What do you mean "no, there is no connection between ajax and functions in views.py" . Do you see any error?

Comment: no error , we are passing input from script to views, but i tried to print the input in views

Comment: def myajaxtestview(request):
    x = request.POST.get('msg')
    print('x is:', x)
    print(request.body)
    return JsonResponse({"message": "My Ajax Test", x: x})

Comment: can u post the corrected url.py , views.py and script fully ? Thanks @NKSM

Comment: Try to change in  urls.py to > `path('ajax-test-view/', views.myajaxtestview, name='ajaxview')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230403/discussion-between-nksm-and-mohan-baabu).

Comment: <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: after using the correct source file, i got the output